# Nodemailer not working only when i use .env

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

First, i created one file config.js with login data, and ok, it’s working. But, when switched to one file .env, the script is not working

.envFILE

```
HOST=smtp.gmail.com
PORTEMAIL=465
USER=test@gmail.com
PASSWORD=123
```

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: process.env.HOST,
  port: process.env.PORTEMAIL,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.USER,
    pass: process.env.PASSWORD,
  }
});
```

It’s only not working with .env

Comment: did you `require("dotenv").config()`? [dotenv docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Comment: How are you reading the .env file?

Comment: `
const path = require("path");
require( 'dotenv' ).config({
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.env')
});`

Comment: Im only calling transporter config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've added

```
require("dotenv").config()
```

before calling

```
nodemailer.createTransport
```

Answer (score 0):

I was starting dotenv in the main app.js file and not in the file where I was using dotenv